# Add items to a shopping cart with Vue?

Tags: vue.js, shopping-cart

I'm trying to figure out how to implement the shopping cart functionality on a page using Vue.js. I get a list of items from an API call and print them on page load. But I'm stuck trying to add items to my cart. The functionality should include the ability to select a quantity of an item and add it to the cart by clicking the "add to cart" button. So it should allow, directly from the cart, to change quantities and remove items from the cart.

Comment: Please share codes not screen shots

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this kind of situation, use a state management pattern like `vuex` (or pinia), and it will store your data after route change also.

For more clear context, go through this link:
https://vuex.vuejs.org/